# dd command on dir

Tags: usb

One could install Linux to stick

```
dd if=./file.iso of=/mnt/sdb
```

When one run the `dd` command as above, error occurs:

```
dd: opening ‘/mnt/’: Is directory
```

Can folder be worked by `dd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you refer to the **mountpoint** instead of the **device file**. `/mnt/sdb` is the place where the usb stick is mounted, not the stick itself.

Use that command instead:

```
dd if=Ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

- `/dev/sdb` is a block special device file. It is a device represented as a file in linux and it refers to the physical device attached to it.
- On the other hand, a mountpoint is just a directory in the system tree, that is associated to the filesystem at the device that is mounted there.

Comment: @NonymousNT - You can output to a file in a directory but you can't output a directory.  You need to specify the output directory/filename.

Comment: @NonymousNT - I think chaos has the correct answer regarding the mountpoint and my comment addressed the general question of dd requiring a filename if you're not writing to a partition.  Your question is specific to dd and that pretty much covers it.  If you are asking a broader question, can you edit the question to clarify?

Comment: @NonymousNT so you want to extract the iso? If yes, you can mount it and copy the content to the desired directory.